# How to import VC++ project in eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I have a vc++ solution which contains few vc++ project. And each project also has make file, meaning we can build it using make command. Now I want to import this whole solution in eclipse.

I am using wascana plugin in eclipse for c++.

Reply soon it is urgent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems there are tools available for converting .vcproj and .sln to makefile. Take a look [this on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cross-platform/sln2mak.aspx)